# There is a problem with calling the function within the function

Tags: c

```
//Program to print the summation of a five-digit or less than 5 digit number entered using recursion.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int summation(long int num) //summation function.
{
    int sum = 0, rem;
    if (num < 10)
        return num;
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            rem = num % 10;
            sum = sum + rem;
            summation(num / 10);
        }
        return sum;
    } //End else.

} //End summation.

int main()
{
    long int data;
    int ans;
    int summation(long int num);
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%ld", &data); //Taking the input of data.
    ans = summation(data); //Calling the funcion.
    printf("%d", ans); //Printing the output.
    getch();
    return 0;
} //End main.
```

In this program, when I called the function by passing the argument as `num/10` then it gave a wrong answer. Instead, if I wrote `num =num/10` and called the function by passing `num` as an argument I got the right answer. Why is this happening? Are both statements the same thing?

Comment: `summation(num / 10);` you are throwing away the return value.

Comment: `int summation(long int num);` not needed inside `main()`.

Comment: Either have explicit iteration (the `for` loop) or use recursion. Don't use both.

Comment: @kaylum can you describe more about what you said.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are not wrong but if the return function executes then the control return to main program so there is no issue with both the for loop and recursion.

Comment: `summation` returns a value. If you don't use that return value then what is the point of calling it at all?

Comment: That's not how recursion work, at least not in C. Calling *any* function (even itself) works just the same, there's no special case for a function calling itself. After calling `summation(num / 10)` the control comes back to execute the code after the call.

Comment: I really suggest you learn how to use a debugger and how to use it to step through your code statement by statement. Step into the recursive call and see what happens when it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing recursion and loops. Use either, but not both. (Of course, the assignment says to use recursion, so do that.)

Loop solution (pseudocode):

```
int summation(number) {
    for (digit in number)
        sum += digit;
    return sum;
}
```

Recursion (pseudocode):

```
int summation(number) {
    if (number < 10) return number;
    else {
        dv = number%10;
        return dv + summation(number // 10);
    }
}
```

Notice how the latter calls itself, and also how that call `return`s the value from the new call to the caller, building a chain between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int summation(int);
int main(){
    int val,sum;
    scanf("%d",&val);
    sum=summation(val<0?-val:val);//We need the absolute value
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
//Get the sum recurcively
int summation(int v){
    if(v==0)
    return 0;
    return (v%10)+summation(v/10);//v%10 is the reminder which is the last digit
}
```

Comment: @Peace does it helps